# FMX client connecting to multiple datasnap servers

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I have 2 VCL datasnap server apps on different servers, each with a different port number. no problems on the server side - all works well.

However, on the FMX client, when I generate datasnap client classes on both of the TSQLConnections, the generated unit is always under the same last saved name, even if it was saved under a different unit name, thus, only the last of the TSQLConnection generated connection methods are exposed/available and the other is not.

What is the workaround to have a generated unit for each TSQLConnection?

Answer (score 1):

The solution worked out well as long as the secondary TSQLConnection is created from the pallet but not as a copy/paste from the original TSQLConnection.